# why does shell save, dup, and restore redirected descriptor in the parent, rather than redirect in the child?

Tags: linux, shell, redirect

I wanted to understand how redirection is implemented in a (POSIX) shell, so I looked at `dash` (the simplest shell) code, and here is how it works.

A dash script like:

```
date > foobar.txt
date
```

is (as an SSCCE) handled like this:

```
int fd;
int saved;

fd = open64("foobar.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
saved = fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10);
dup2(fd, 1);
if (!fork()) {
    execl("/bin/date", "date", (char *)NULL);
}
dup2(saved, 1);

if (!fork()) {
    execl("/bin/date", "date", (char *)NULL);
}
```

This is strange.  Why save, dup and dup again to restore, descriptors in the parent, when it would be much simpler to just dup in the child, and not have to save and restore.  This is simpler and I checked it works the same:

```
int fd;

if (!fork()) {
    fd = open64("foobar.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
    dup2(fd, 1);
    execl("/bin/date", "date", (char *)NULL);
}

if (!fork()) {
    execl("/bin/date", "date", (char *)NULL);
}
```

I am sure there must be a good reason and I am not understanding something deeper.  What is it?

Comment: Curiously, Bash exhibits the second (simpler) behavior. I don't know why Dash does what it does either.

Comment: @ephemient thank you - bash is so darn complex that I was too lazy to look into it.  What you are saying probably means there is no good reason, since bash implements everything dash does.  If you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it (unless later an opposing answer comes up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No good reason as far as I can tell. Bash does things in the opposite order, and the externally observable behavior is the same.

I didn't bother reading the source code, it's easy enough to see what happens using `strace`. (The `:` is to prevent the shell from optimizing away the `fork`.)

```
$ strace -fetrace=dup2,file,process dash -c 'date > foobar.txt; :'
execve("/usr/bin/dash", ["dash", "-c", "date > foobar.txt; :"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
open("foobar.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
stat("/usr/bin/date", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=105280, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f6650bf2750) = 1948
strace: Process 1948 attached
[pid  1947] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1948] execve("/usr/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
[pid  1948] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid  1948] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 1948
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1948, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

```
$ strace -fetrace=dup2,file,process bash -c 'date > foobar.txt; :'                  
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "date > foobar.txt; :"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/date", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=105280, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/bin/date", R_OK)           = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd5b78349d0) = 2026
strace: Process 2026 attached
[pid  2025] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2026] open("foobar.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
[pid  2026] dup2(3, 1)                  = 1
[pid  2026] execve("/usr/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
[pid  2026] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid  2026] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 2026
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=2026, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, 0x7ffeffe03c50, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```